# How to convert json into string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 var mydata = JSON.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
```

when I convert JSON file data to string it throws "Undefine name JSON"

Comment: try `json`, not `JSON`, more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/json-constant.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

and then Change your code

```
var mydata = JSON.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
```

to

```
var mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **json** not **JSON**, Also make sure to import [dart-convert-library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.1/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html)

```
import 'dart:convert';

var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
```